# Server startup script for networking

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, startup

I am running Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS.  It is located in a data center in a different state.  Sometimes it is on a private network (with internet access) and other times it needs to be directly on the internet.  What I would like is a script that runs at startup (at which point, assistance would greatly be appreciated!).  First, it would use a pre-defined static IP, netmask and gateway.  If it can ping a public IP (such as 8.8.8.8), then continue booting.  If not, then try DHCP and then continue booting.

If the system has a valid internet connection, then it I would like for it to send me an email with its interface IP and also its internet (NATed) IP.

This is similar to a question asked before ([How to use DHCP if available, otherwise use static IP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/698624/how-to-use-dhcp-if-available-otherwise-use-static-ip)), but was never answered.

Comment: I cannot see how this is a Good Thing, so it's hard for me to help. Could you explain the two network cases?

Comment: As I explained, sometime the system needs to be on a LAN with DHCP, other times it needs to be on the internet with a static IP.  The system is located in a different state and the person(s) that may move it are unfamiliar with any console.